# google sheets api fails with missing parameter: spreadsheetId

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to work with a google spreadsheet and the spreadsheet API.  Following the directions, I have written the following:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: 'keys.json',
    scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
});
    const authClientObject = auth.getClient();
    const googleSheetInstance = google.sheets({version: 'v4',auth: authClientObject})
    const spreadSheetId = 'customsheetid';
    const result = googleSheetInstance.spreadsheets.values.get({
        spreadSheetId,
        range:'sheet1'
    })
```

My problem is that it keeps failing.  Any time I run this I get: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Missing required parameters: spreadsheetId`.  Everything that I have read and looked at on both the official docs and StackOverflow, my get statement should be written correctly.  But clearly, I am missing something and would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `spreadSheetId: spreadSheetId,`?

Comment: @TheWizEd nope does not fix it.  Also there own docs show it as just `spreadSheetId` https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#reading

Answer (score 1):

I needed to change the variable name.  I took it from `spreadSheetId` to `spreadsheetId`.